# Check Array1 if it has a match in Array3 from Array2

Tags: arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
    Array1 = ["banana", "lemon", "meat"];
    Array2 = [
    {id: 0; name: "BananaSplit"; ingredients: ["banana", "milk", "suggar"]},
    {id: 1; name: "LemonJuice"; ingredients: ["lemon", "juice", "suggar"]},
    {id: 2; name: "Chicken"; ingredients: ["meat", "salt", "checkup"]},
    {id: 3; name: "Popcorn"; ingredients: ["corn", "salt"]}
    ]
```

Array3 is the Ingredients inside Array2, I am trying to check if the Array1 has a match with any ingredient inside Array2, then OUTPUT the Data.

If "banana" found output: {id: 0; name: "BananaSplit"; ingredients: ["banana", "milk", "suggar"]}

I tried a lot of versions but stopped at this:

```
let restul = (array2.ingredients).filter(value => -1 !== array1.indexOf(value))
console.log(restul);
```

I get a array with results of common ingredients, but not on what Recipe.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code please.

Comment: @Akrion I have updated the question, thanks.